How can I make an ajax call asynchronously from Javascript to mvc controller method and to wait for the result to proceed to next line of code
I am trying to get the result from the function called 'validateScheduleDate()' and only if the result comes from the function, then next line of code should be executed. I am trying to validate two dates to find these dates are between the given time frame.
Right now, it does not wait for the result from the function called 'validateScheduleDate'
Here is my code in Jvascript
$wizard.wizard({
    validateTab: function (currentTab) {
        validateScheduleDate().then(function (data) {

            if (data != 'noDifference') {
                // Not passed to the next line                       
            }

        }); 

        switch (currentTab.index()) {
            case 0: // tabPaneNames.general
                return  validateSales1()
            case 1: // tabPaneNames.problems
                return  validateSales2()
            case 2: // tabPaneNames.serviceProviders
                return  validateSales3()           
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
});
  $('[submit-sales').click(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();  
      
      validateScheduleDate().then(function (data) {

          if (data == 'noDifference') {
              validateTabs(function () { submitForm(); }, true);
          }
          else{
                 // Not passed to the next line
              }

           
      });
 
  });   


 function validateScheduleDate() {
     var startDate = document.getElementById('dispatch-start-date').value;
     var startTime = document.getElementById('ddl-dispatch-times').value;
     var arrivalTimeFrame = parseFloat(document.getElementById("hdn-WOArrivalTimeFrame-id").value).toFixed(2);
     var scheduledDate = document.getElementById("ScheduledDate").value;
     var scheduledTime = document.getElementById("ddl-dispatch-scheduled-times").value;
     var dateErrorSpan = document.getElementById("ScheduledDate-Error");  
     var timeErrorSpan = document.getElementById("ScheduledTime-Error");;

     var resultdata =  $.get('/WorkOrderDispatch/GetScheduledEndDate', {
         dispStartDate: startDate, dispStartTime: startTime, dispTimeFrame: arrivalTimeFrame,
         dispScheduledDate: scheduledDate, dispScheduledTime: scheduledTime
     }).done(function (result) {
         
         if (result == 'hasDaysDifference') {
             timeErrorSpan.textContent = '';
             dateErrorSpan.textContent = 'Enter the Scheduled Date within the arrival time frame ' + arrivalTimeFrame + ' Hrs'
             $wizard.wizard('changeTo', '#' + tabPaneNames.general);
             return false;
         }
         else if (result == 'hasTimeDifference')
         {
             dateErrorSpan.textContent = '';
             timeErrorSpan.textContent = 'Enter the Scheduled Date within the arrival time frame ' + arrivalTimeFrame + ' Hrs'  
             $wizard.wizard('changeTo', '#' + tabPaneNames.general);
             return false;
         }
         else {
             dateErrorSpan.textContent = '';
             timeErrorSpan.textContent = '';
            
             return true;
         }
     });           
     return resultdata;
    
 }

Code in MVC controller
 public async Task<JsonResult> GetScheduledEndDate(string dispStartDate, string dispStartTime, string dispTimeFrame, string dispScheduledDate, string dispScheduledTime)        {

     var UserID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
     var loginUser = await DbContext.Employees.Where(x => x.ApplicationUserID == UserID).FirstOrDefaultAsync(); 

     if (loginUser == null)
     {
         throw new OfficetraxException(ErrorCode.NotFound);
     }            
     TimeZoneInfo employeeTimeZone = TimeZoneTools.FindTimeZone(loginUser.TimeZone);
     DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
     string DispatchNowString = "[Dispatch Now]";
     DateTime startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dispStartDate);
    
     DateTime scheduledDate;
     DateTime? dispatchScheduledDate = null;

     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dispScheduledDate))
     {
           scheduledDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dispScheduledDate);
           dispatchScheduledDate = scheduledDate.ApplyTimeAndTimeZone(dispScheduledTime, employeeTimeZone);
     }

     double? arrivalTimeFrame = Convert.ToDouble(dispTimeFrame);
     string combinedscheduleDate = dispScheduledDate + " " + dispScheduledTime;
     
     DateTime dispatchStartDate = dispStartTime == DispatchNowString ? now : startDate.ApplyTimeAndTimeZone(dispStartTime, employeeTimeZone); 

     DateTime? scheduledEndDate = arrivalTimeFrame.HasValue ?
                                        dispatchStartDate.AddHours(arrivalTimeFrame.Value) : (DateTime?)null;

     

     //DateTime? dispatchScheduledDate = DateTime.Parse(combinedscheduleDate); 

     if (scheduledEndDate.HasValue && dispatchScheduledDate.HasValue)
     {
         if(dispatchScheduledDate < dispatchStartDate)
         {
             if (dispatchScheduledDate.Value.Date == dispatchStartDate.Date)
             {
                 return Json("hasTimeDifference", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
             }
             else
             {
                 return Json("hasDaysDifference", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
             }
         }
         if(dispatchScheduledDate > scheduledEndDate)
         {
             if(dispatchScheduledDate.Value.Date == scheduledEndDate.Value.Date)
             {
                 return Json("hasTimeDifference", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
             }
             else
             {
                 return Json("hasDaysDifference", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
             }
             
         }
         else
         {
             return Json("noDifference", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
         }
     }
     return Json("noDifference", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

     
 }


$('[submit-sales') this appears to use jQuery but this is NOT a valid selector here - perhaps update with the jQuery version tag if that is the case and work to fix things

You need to move your "next line of code" to inside validateScheduleDate().then(

Your method validateScheduleDate does not return a Promise and does not assign value you expect in resultdata.
To correct that behavior, you would need to first mark it async for cleaner syntax and in order to return Promise and leverage then method correctly.
So, corrected version of your method would look like this:
async function validateScheduleDate() {
    //...

    // HERE YOU ARE AWAITING THE CALL, giving the change for resultdata
    // to be populated.
    var resultdata =  await $.get('/WorkOrderDispatch/GetScheduledEndDate', {
        dispStartDate: startDate, dispStartTime: startTime, dispTimeFrame: arrivalTimeFrame,
        dispScheduledDate: scheduledDate, dispScheduledTime: scheduledTime
    })
    // other cahined methods, which you need to refactor         
    return resultdata;
}

Now your implementation
validateScheduleDate().then(function (data) {
    if (data != 'noDifference') {
        // Not passed to the next line                       
    }
});

is perfectly valid.

I tried your code , but still going to the next line of code before calling the function  validateScheduleDate

To what line exactly ? where is the problem?
